# java.lang.NullPointerException SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

So I am having a very weird problem, probably easily solvable to anybody else but me ;-)
Anyway, I am having many Activities and on every Activity I have to problem to get it to resume properly, every Activity but one.

Whenever I start that one activity, or put that one activity to sleep and immediately return to it, it works fine. But when I put it to sleep hit the home button and launch a bunch of different apps and then try to return to it again I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException at getSharedPreferences.

How can this even happen? Do the SharedPreferences get deleted?

here is my getPreferences method where the error happens:

```
private static SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    Context applicationContext = App.getContextOfApplication();
    return applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): Process: com.test, PID: 13767
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.test.LocalStorage.getPreferences(LocalStorage.java:30)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.test.LocalStorage.getUsername(LocalStorage.java:83)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.test.WebApi.getChat(WebApi.java:711)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at com.test.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:100)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-16 20:37:36.461: E/AndroidRuntime(13767):    ... 11 more
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `applicationContext ` seems to be `null`. Please show implementation of `App.getContextOfApplication()`.

Comment: Do not try and get/store a static reference to a `Context`. Everytime you do, a small kitten dies :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Niek_Haarman indicated, you cannot rely on a static reference to a `Context` instance, even if it  is an `Application` instance, since the Android system can destroy and reconstruct `Application` and `Activity` instances. So, if `App.getContextOfApplication()` is returning a static variable value, that may be what is going wrong.

Is there a reason `getPreferences()` must be `static`? If you can make it a non-static method of your `Activity`, then you should have no problem using the `Activity` itself as the `Context`:

```
private SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Comment: sadly in this case getPreferences is not from an Activity its from a class which handles the SharedPreferences so I have no context there to usw. If App.getContextOfApplication() is so bad why do all the examples suggest just that?

Comment: There is no standard `getContextOfApplication()`. There *is* a `Context.getApplicationContext()`, but you need to have a `Context` instance in order to call that, so that will not help you.

Comment: And how can the activity have a context but not the application?

Comment: `Context` is an abstract class. `Application` and `Activity` inherit from it. So, an `Activity` does not "have" a `Context` -- it *is* a `Context`.

Comment: So I use the context from my activity on the class which has the getPreferences method instead of using the cstatic context from the Application class. Right?

Comment: You can use *any* live `Context` instance. The current `Actvity`'s instance would work fine.